# Calculate max value by a dimension over a number of days in SQL (Presto)

Tags: sql, max, presto

I am looking to get the max value by a specific dimension over a number of days in SQL, as per example below:

I have this initial dataset: 
[image]

And I am looking to calculate the maximum of nr of items and sales by product type across the number of days, as in the example below:

Expected output:

[image]

Any advise on best way to get this? I tried Max function and Max_by to get the max by product id but it didnt work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: we don't see any dataset.

Comment: thanks @zealous. just added in the post

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(items) over (partition by product_type),
       max(sales) over (partition by product_type)
from t;
```